# STUFF Not Sorting Dates in SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a pivot where we have columns of week dates - The stuff command isn't sorting by dateweek, am I doing something incorrectly ? The dates do not appear in any order at all e.g. 2019-01-07, 2020-02-24,2003-01-13,2020-12-21,2019-01-21

```
select product, expected, CAST(weekdue AS date) as dateweek into #tempemma from weekdueview 


DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';


set @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.dateweek) 
        FROM (SELECT TOP(99.99) PERCENT dateweek FROM #tempemma ORDER BY dateweek desc) c 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') 

select @cols 

   DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
select product, expected, dateweek from #tempemma
) src
pivot 
(
sum(expected) for dateweek in (' + @cols + ')
) piv
' 


   execute(@query)

   drop table #tempemma
```

How can I sort this by the dateweek column ?

Comment: "*How can I sort this by the dateweek column ?"* With an `ORDER BY`. Sample data and expected results would help us help you. But `dateweek` isn't a column in your final dataset, it's the column that's been pivoted.

Comment: STUFF doesn't sort anything, it only inserts one string into another. In *this case, it actually deletes the first character*. You're using the XML string aggregation method. The part that actually aggregates the strings is `FOR XML PATH('')`.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? SQL Server 2017 introduced [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: This a a new one for me   TOP(99.99) PERCENT

Comment: @JohnCappelletti just me playing around trying to sort the dates

Comment: For when you don't want that 10,000th row, @JohnCappelletti ;)

Comment: @Emma sort the dates or the *columns*? Have you tried *just* the string aggregation query? Again, `STUFF` doesn't order or aggregate anything. It just deletes the first character ( a leading `,`)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -- I had a flashback -- don't remember the details totally -- I think it was on some platform where you could not sort views and if you selected top 99.9% of the data from the view you could sort it -- if you didn't then the optimizer would stop you from using the order by.  Not even sure if it was sql server or not -- hazy

Comment: @Hogan I recall an issue where TOP 100% wasn't doing the job so I settle for TOP 10000 (a ridiculous number for the sample)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -- oh good point -- top 99% is strange when top 100% works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a little example which will sort the columns

```
Declare @YourTable table (dateweek date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2019-01-07'),('2019-01-07'),('2020-02-24'),('2003-01-13'),('2020-12-21'),('2019-01-21')

Select stuff((Select distinct  ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),dateweek, 23)) 
               From @YourTable
               Order By 1
               For XML Path('') )
            ,1,1,'')
```

**NOTE:**  Corrected for Lanu's keen observation.

Comment: *Might* be worth using `CONVERT` and style code here instead of trusting the implicit conversion to a `varchar`. This works (for me, and I assume yourself) for `date`, but goes very wrong with a `datetime`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=663a210c32523c5e7d601d21dd579f3e)

Comment: @Larnu Good point, we don't see any indication of datetime in the question, but we both know it may be case.

Comment: The fact that the OP has `CAST(weekdue AS date)` in their first SQL statement does infer that `weekdue` isn't a `date` though; hence my concern. :)